# converting from dropdown to input textbox using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sorry for the title.

How do I modify this code from dropdown to input textbox in such that instead of populating dropdown, input textbox will be populated from getCustomer.php code?

```
function getOrgCodes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCustomer.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(orgInfo) {
        $(orgInfo).each(function(i, orgdisplay) {
            $('<option>').val(orgdisplay.ORGANIZATION).text(orgdisplay.ORGANIZATION).appendTo( $('#deptId') );
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<option>` with `<input type="text">`.

```
function getOrgCodes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCustomer.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(orgInfo) {
        $(orgInfo).each(function(i, orgdisplay) {
            $('<input type="text">').val(orgdisplay.ORGANIZATION).appendTo( $('#deptId') );
        })
    });
}
```

You dont need that `.text(orgdisplay.ORGANIZATION)` after you do the replacement. `.val(orgdisplay.ORGANIZATION)` will set the value inside the textbox.

See this mini-demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/hfczjzhy/